# Docker-compose working on Windows but not on Ubuntu

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx, docker-compose

The same code with the same containers is working in Windows but not on Ubuntu and this is the error page:

[image]

##### `docker-compose ps` on Windows

```
NAME                IMAGE                                      COMMAND                  SERVICE             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS
Laravel_nginx       nginx:stable-alpine                        "/docker-entrypoint.…"   nginx               2 days ago          Up 21 seconds       0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp
Laravel_php         dockerized-laravel-8-vue3-typescript-php   "docker-php-entrypoi…"   php                 2 days ago          Up 22 seconds       0.0.0.0:9001->9000/tcp
```

##### `docker-compose ps` on Ubuntu

```
       Name                    Command              State               Ports             
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
laravel_nginx      docker-php-entrypoint php-fpm   Up      0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp, 9000/tcp
laravel_php        docker-php-entrypoint php-fpm   Up      9000/tcp
```

I think there is an issue with the port mapping in Ubuntu

##### `docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: '3'

networks:
  webapp:

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}_nginx
    ports:
    - "8080:80"
    links:
      - php
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - ./docker/nginx/site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:rw
      - ./docker/logs/nginx:/var/logs/nginx:rw
    depends_on:
      - php
    networks:
      - webapp
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}_php
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "9001:9000"
    networks:
      - webapp
```

Comment: You should not care at all about exposing port `9000` on windows or ubuntu, that is internal for the PHP FPM worker. You should only care about the NGINX. Check the logs `docker-compose logs nginx`. But I see you have `8080` and on linux is `8000` (did you manually change the file?)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  And provide the commands verbatim, for example showing the logs of the services you're running inside the containers, as well as those of the apps that send empty responses under circumstances. Without this information there is little to say if not with much too much to guess. And have you tried burning it down, rebooting the host and building it fresh again?

Comment: Maybe it's only a copy paste error, but your portmapping in the docker-composer.yaml file is missing the indent. Seems only to affect the Windows Version. There Port 8000 is mapped to 80.